# An error is reported when the local database is linked through SSH , 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, linux

This problem has bothered me for several hours.

[image]

Comment: What is "this problem"? Can you share the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: There's no way of us to know if the problem is your code, MySQL setup or something else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry that I didn't describe the problem carefully, but through my efforts and attempts, I understand that the reason for the error is that my server database is not open to the channel of external links, that is mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON*.*TO'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY'xxxxxx'WITH GRANT OPTION;Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.